# Can I serve with a custom protocol using PHP?

Tags: php

I use shared hosting and I want to serve with a custom protocol. Let's name the protocol 'foo'. Can someone communicate with foo://mydomain.com/moo.blo ? Is it possible to do something like this using sockets or whatever? I don't know the purpose of sockets. And can I serve over a specific port?

Comment: It sounds like you don't even know what you're asking.

Comment: That's something of a complex question. Generally yes, you can do that using PHP, but very likely specifically not on shared hosting. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @deceze, I want to write a custom protocol. Nothing spesific in my mind. I see servers here https://pay.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/s9t3k/im_trying_to_find_really_unique_mindboggling_php/ written in PHP

Comment: @george: A server is not the same as a protocol. A protocol is a standard dialog between two machines (or humans for that matter).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, I'm not exactly sure if this is how you deal with this, but it should go something like this:

- on the server (`/etc/services`) add a new protocol to listen on a specific port (i.e.: `foo` = `1500`)
- code a new daemon in PHP to listen and reply on that port
- on the client register the same protocol / port and have it communicate with the server

Bare in mind that the protocol doesn't need to be HTTP, and you probably won't be able to use your regular browser on the client. Sorry for the vagueness of the answer, but I really don't know any better.

[ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a more appropriate place to ask this type of stuff.